# NuGet package breaks when publishing with the 'trim unused code' option

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6.0 project written in C# and Visual Studio that uses the `System.Management` NuGet package.

When publishing my project as self-contained, I use the 'trim unused code' option to reduce the file size. However, when I try to run my executable a `System.TypeInitializationException` is thrown with the following message:

> The type initializer for 'System.Management.WmiNetUtilsHelper' threw an exception

This is the line of code it occurs on:

```
ManagementClass mgmt = new("Win32_ComputerSystem");
```

This only happens when I use the 'trim unused code' option.

I tried changing some other publishing settings but the exception stayed the same.

Comment: This is expected, described in the docs and probably caused some trim warnings too. Trimming means that types that aren't referenced directly will be removed. The compiler can't detect types that are loaded using reflection or referenced through COM. WMI works through COM.

Comment: There's a related [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78038) specifically about System.Management. The workarounds there explain how to configure trimming to include the necessary COM wrappers